# FFmpeg: Tee Muxer not saving a local copy

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

Tee Muxer is this very awesome feature but has a minimal amount of documentation and examples to help explain it.

I am trying to stream to multiple streaming servers (Facebook & Youtube for now) and save a local copy, it streamed to Facebook but I have two problems here:

1- I can't save a local copy of the live stream to a custom location

2- YouTube isn't receiving my video saying that it's [65kx65k pixels as shown in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A72Un.png).

Note: I doubt there's a problem in filter_complex because it used to save locally before live-streaming through tee mux.

This is my command, I'll paste it almost as it is so that you can tell where's the issue:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="video-input-device":audio="audio-input-device" 
       -i "logo.png" 
       -filter_complex "crop=1360:768:0:0[cropped];[cropped]pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2[scaledagain];[scaledagain]scale=1360x768[unscaled];[unscaled]scale=1280:-2,overlay=0:0[output]" 
       -c:a aac -strict experimental -ab 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -bt 500k 
       -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -b:v 1500K -bufsize 750K -minrate 1000K -maxrate 2000K -framerate 30 -threads 0 
       -f tee -map [output] -map 0:a "C:\Users\User\Desktop\output.flv|[f=flv]youtubeRtmpLink/key|[f=flv]facebookRtmpLink/key"
```

Is there any workaround the problem of a local copy in a custom location?

Thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-flags +global_header` as the tee docs say.

And for local saving, escape the path elements

`"C:\Users\User\Desktop\output.flv"` --> `"C\:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\output.flv"`

Comment: Man you're a life saver, thank you so much for your contribution for ffmpeg students and the community, it worked, even for youtube somehow